# X-Mouse Button Control is not working with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, scroll, mouse

I'm using this software [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) in order to scroll down multiple windows without setting the focus on a specific windows. This feature is supported in Mac but not in Windows 7. The aforementioned software is working fine except with Visual Studio (i.e. VS 2010). I have no idea why. Any suggestions?